# Hide a large element without using display:none or visibility:hidden

Tags: html, css, web, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is it possible to hide an element without using display:none, visibility:hidden or opactiy:0 CSS rules?

At the moment anything I try, the content of the  still remains relatively the same (Note: I am using Bootstrap 3)

I mostly need to only use elements that are normally used for styling, rather than hiding/showing the content directly, so things like Opacity, display:none and visibility:hidden wouldn't work. (It's to show some bad behaviour I found in a particular version of a browser, wanted to confirm it on other browsers with a controlled set)

Comment: What exactly you want to hide and how about posting your line of code, will easy to understand.

Comment: do you want to complety remove or somthing ? or just hide only ?

Comment: I meant purely hide, but the browser still rendering something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry guys, I managed to figure it out immediately after posting, what I used:

```
position:fixed !important;
height:1px !important;
width:1px !important;
bottom:0 !important;
left:0 !important;
z-index:-999 !important;
display:inline !important;
```

Just to give some more context into the CSS rules given above. Height and width as 1px for the obvious reasons of making it as small as possible. The position being fixed but placing it constantly outside of the browsers visibility by place it at the 0th pixel from the bottom and the 0th pixel from the left. I made everything !important so it over rides anything that might be cascaded.

Comment: Consider editing your answer so it looks more like an answer (right now it is unclear if this comment to your post, answer, or both). You may want to put requirements into question and keep the rest in answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try `opacity:0;`. This will make that element transparent.

Answer (score 1):

```
.classname{
    position:absolute; 
    left:-2000px;
}
```